# Minimize effort separate pdf and single pdf versions; ref and url issues

Tags: macros, hyperref, urls

I want to create LaTeX content which consists of many sections.
I will **either** typeset all of the sections together to get **one PDF**
or **typeset each one separately**. If they are typeset together, then
I want to be able to use label/ref to create links. If they are typeset
separately, then I get a link to the relevant PDF instead of the links to 
the appropriate sections.

I have an OK start, but I am not sure of the next steps.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
\section{a}
\label{a-label}
Text for a
See also \mychoose{(\ref{b-label})}{\url{./only-b.pdf}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.tex}
\section{b}
\label{b-label}
Text for b
See also \mychoose{(\ref{a-label})}{\url{./only-a.pdf}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{only-a.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\mychoose[2]{#2}
\begin{document}
\input a.tex
\end{document}\end
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{only-b.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\mychoose[2]{#2}
\begin{document}
\input b.tex
\end{document}\end
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{together.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand\mychoose[2]{#1}
\begin{document}
\input a.tex
\input b.tex
\end{document}\end
\end{filecontents}
\end{document}\end
```

Typeset it once to see the files a.tex, b.tex, only-a.tex,
only-b.tex and together.tex.

This allows me to create the document with the two sections
(by typesetting together.tex). I can create the document consisting
of just section "a" (by typesetting only-a.tex). The **url** command
does not work. Also, there is a lot of typing involved to use the 
mychoose command as demonstrated above. Suggestions welcome!

**NOTES:**

1. The files "a.tex" and "b.tex" are similar (and there 
   differences are easy to see).
2. The files "together.tex", "only-a.tex" and 
   "only-b.tex" are similar (and their differences are involve different number 
   of input commands and #1 vs #2).
3. I can create the "only-" documents 
   using a computer program and so am not concerned about the duplication.

Better ideas are welcome.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Interesting question. There are stray `\end` comments in the `only-...` `filecontents` environments, but they will be ignored, since they occur after `\end{document}`. You could use a common preamble `.sty` file for all documents there, even with `\begin{filecontents}{mycommon.sty}....\end{filecontents}` etc. where you hold some of the commands.

Comment: Take a look at the package `docmute` which I used to produce either a master file or individual files.   This question with my answer is an example of using 'docmute'. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245138/is-there-any-way-to-read-arbitrary-part-of-external-tex-file/245146#245146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, the external references should be made with `xr-hyper` and `\href{filename#ext-label}{some-text}`, where some text is the same as the filename ('url').

Using a common style file for all (sub)documents reduces the typing and in my point of view the `\mychoose` command is not needed here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mycommon.sty}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
\section{a}
\label{a-label}
Text for a
See also \href{only-b.pdf#b-label}{only-b.pdf}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.tex}
\section{b}
\label{b-label}
Text for b
See also \href{only-a.pdf#a-label}{only-a.pdf}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{only-a.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycommon}
\begin{document}
\input a.tex
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{only-b.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycommon}
\begin{document}
\input b.tex
\end{document}\end
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{together.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycommon}
\begin{document}
\input a.tex
\input b.tex
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\end{document}
```

**Update**: With `\ifinternalref` conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mycommon.sty}
\newif\ifinternalref
\internalreffalse % First disable the internal references
\newcommand{\quickref}[2]{%
  \ifinternalref%
  \cref{#1}%  or just \ref{#1}
  \else
  \href{#2\##1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}%

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % Last package! 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{mycommon}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
\section{a}
\label{a-label}
Text for a

See also \quickref{b-label}{only-b.pdf} and \quickref{einstein}{only-b.pdf}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.tex}
\section{b}
\label{b-label}
Text for b

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2 \label{einstein}
\end{equation}

See \quickref{a-label}{only-a.pdf} and this internal reference \cref{einstein}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{only-a.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycommon}
\begin{document}
\input a.tex
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{only-b.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycommon}
\begin{document}
\input b.tex
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{together.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mycommon}
\internalreftrue  % Enable the internal references since all is combined
\begin{document}
\input a.tex
\clearpage % Just for testing
\input b.tex
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Comment: The `\url` package is of no use here, in my point of view, since it is only meant for formatting url, not for linking. The `url` command used from `url` package is comparable to `\nolinkurl` from `hyperref`, producing no hyperlink.

Comment: I didn't know about xr-hyper! This is great. I still had problems with the link, but I also found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files which answered by question.

Comment: @user738419: You don't need it really, only for `\ref` usage. And it has to be setup still. I am thinking about another solution, perhaps, but not right now.

Comment: When I typeset the document as one large document, I want to link from the given document (together.pdf) to itself.

Comment: @user738419: Yes, that's an issue. I'll think about it

Comment: @user738419: Do you need specific references (e.g. Eq. 1.2) when referring to external labels (e.g. to an Equation from `only-b.pdf` or is **See only-b.pdf` sufficient?

Comment: Referring to the file itself is enough for the external references. I am looking for  a macro which is like "concatenate". So a macro \cool{xyz} could expand into \href{only-xyz.pdf#a-label}{xyz-a.pdf} and another macro \hot{xyz} expands to \ref{xyz-label}.

Comment: @user738419: Well, not with `\cool` and `\hot`, but with `\quickref`?

Comment: Thanks Christian. It is perfect. I will mark it as solved.